# 定数エラー　'const' (T_CONST)

Tags: php

PHPで以下の定数エラーが起きます。なぜでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST)
```

**該当のコード:**

```
const $ABBB = 300;
```

**実行環境:**

```
% php -version
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:22) ( NTS )
```

以下の関数の中でエラーが起きました。

```
    public function getYourAnswer($stack)
    {
       　$calcCost = 0;
        const INITIAL_COST = 300;

        $calcCost = calculate();

        $totalCost =  $calcCost + INITIAL_COST;
        return $totalCost;
    }
```

Comment: その定数定義はクラス定義内に存在しますか? そうしたはずと思われる場合には、クラス定義全体をお示しください。また定数名の先頭には`$`は付けません。

Answer (score 0):

PHPでは定数には`$`を付けません。

```php
const ABBB = 300;
```

しかし、それにしてはエラーメッセージはちょっと違うことを言っているようです。
おそらく問題はその行ではなく1つ前までのコードに何か問題があると思われます。
たぶん文末のセミコロン`;`が無いとか。
確認してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 仰る通り$取り除いてみましたがエラー解消しませんでした

Answer (score 0):

PHPでは、全ての変数宣言の位置で`const`による定数宣言が書けるわけではありません。

(また、@ItagakiFumihiko さんの回答にあるように定数名には`$`は付けません。)

例えば、以下のようにクラス定数を宣言することならできます。

```
class MyClass {
    private const INITIAL_COST = 300;
    
    public function getYourAnswer($stack)
    {
        $calcCost = 0;
        
        $calcCost = calculate();
        
        $totalCost =  $calcCost + MyClass::INITIAL_COST;
        return $totalCost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public`が付いていることから想像するに、`getYourAnswer`はクラスのメソッドですか？
いずれにしてもクラスのメソッドや通常の関数内でconstで定数を定義することはできません。
定義するなら外です。

```
class hogehoge {

    const INITIAL_COST = 300;

    public function getYourAnswer($stack)
    {
        $calcCost = 0;

        $calcCost = calculate();

        $totalCost =  $calcCost + INITIAL_COST;
        return $totalCost;
    }
}
```

`INITIAL_COST`を関数スコープ内に置きたいのなら、定数である必要があるかも検討してください。通常の変数でも良いのではないですか？

それから、質問とは関係ありませんが、提示されたコードには全角スペースが入っているため、そこでもエラーになります。

Answer (score 0):

`define()` での宣言と比較して `const` キーワードには以下の制限があります。

[PHP: Constants Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

> **Note**:
>  As opposed to defining constants using define(), constants defined using the **const keyword must be declared at the top-level scope because they are defined at compile-time. This means that they cannot be declared inside functions, loops, if statements or try/catch blocks**.